# jQuery confirm dialogue with link

Tags: jquery

I have a link that when clicked opens a dialogue and when a CONFIRM button in the dialog is clicked the user needs to be sent to a specific URL via GET action with some variables  (original link). Clearly, if CANCEL is clicked, void link click action.

Not really sure how to put this all together. Here's what I've go so far.

**JS**

```
$("#doSomething").click(function(){
        $("#myConfirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Continue": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    // go to url...
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="page.php?var=1" id="doSomething">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (inside the handler of your continue button):

```
window.location = "page.php?var=1";
```

**Edit 1: Complete code.**

```
$("#doSomething").click(function(){
    $("#myConfirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function() {
                window.location = "page.php?var=1"; // you can create the URL as you like...
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit 2: Complete code with link click.**

**HTML:**

```
<a id="myHyperlink" href="#">Link</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#myHyperlink").click(function(){
    $("#myConfirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function() {
                window.location = "page.php?var=1"; // you can create the URL as you like...
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great. But I need to make it dynamic, something like this: window.location = $(this).attr("href"); But, I can not redirect the moment they click. The redirect should only happen after they click CONTINUE button, and if they click CANCEL only the dialogue should close, without any redirect. How do I do that?

Comment: As I said, inside the continue handler. "Continue": function() { window.localtion = "page.php?var=1"; }. You dont need to close the dialog, since the user will be redirected. I updated my post.

Comment: The moment I click <a href="..."> it starts the redirect, regardless of JS function... That's where i need to halt it until confirmation.

Comment: So, you need to click the link and open the dialog? Is it? I'm asking since it is not explained in your question, at least I didn't undertood this.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to put ID in my link. Fixed in OP

Comment: Ok! The new code is ok now? You just need to change the href value to "#".

Comment: I can't do that. I use a class that encrypts $_GET strings and I need it to be there in order to encrypt on click. So I would need to grab already encrypted URL with attr("href")...

Answer (score -1):

add an ajax call at // go to url.

```
$.ajax({
         url: yourUrl,
         beforeSend: function() {
              // do something like show a loading image
         },
         success: function() {
              // do something like hide the loading image
         },
         error: function() {
              // do something like hide a loading image and alert error message
         }
});
```

Comment: can you comment why this is not useful?